# Multitouch webpages for non-iPhone devices

Tags: javascript, html, multi-touch

I read this : http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/ which I find very interesting as a mobile developer. Do you have any link to do this on other mobile platforms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only found a framework that works for both Android and the iPhone. It will be available on Android and Nokia in the next version though :

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

there's also http://jqtouch.com/ (I think it works on android since it's webkit based)